# Trying to create a function that changes the text of an html file

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function chumpage() {
  chump = document.getElementByClassName("first-txt");
  for (var i = 0; i < chump.length(); i++) {
    chump[i].innerText = "temp3";
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .temp {
      margin: 3%;
      position: relative;
    }

    .first-txt {
      position: absolute;
      top: 17px;
      left: 50px;
    }

    .second-txt {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 10px;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="temp">
    <img src="">
    <h3 class="first-txt">
      Temp1
    </h3>

    <h3 class="second-txt">
      Temp2
    </h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So my goal here is to change the contents of temp1 to temp3 using js, however the above function is not working, the image not being present right now is not an issue. I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: you are not calling your function anywhere in the code tho. How is that function supposed to work and change the text? is it based on an onchange? or something?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to call the method, and it's not `getElementByClassName` it's `getElementsByClassName`.

And chump.length is not a function.

```js
function chumpage() {
  const chump = document.getElementsByClassName("first-txt");
  for (var i = 0; i < chump.length; i++) {
    chump[i].innerText = "temp3";
  }
}

chumpage();
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .temp {
      margin: 3%;
      position: relative;
    }

    .first-txt {
      position: absolute;
      top: 17px;
      left: 50px;
    }

    .second-txt {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 10px;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="temp">
    <img src="">
    <h3 class="first-txt">
      Temp1
    </h3>

    <h3 class="second-txt">
      Temp2
    </h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled

`document.getElementByClassName("first-txt");`

Change it to :

`document.getElementsByClassName("first-txt");`

And `chump.length` not `chump.length()`

Code same as :

```js
function chumpage() {
  chump = document.getElementsByClassName("first-txt");
  for (var i = 0; i < chump.length; i++) {
    chump[i].innerText = "temp3"
  }
}
chumpage()
```

```css
.temp {
      margin: 3%;
      position: relative;
    }

    .first-txt {
      position: absolute;
      top: 17px;
      left: 50px;
    }

    .second-txt {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="temp">
  <img src="">
  <h3 class="first-txt">
    Temp1
  </h3>

  <h3 class="second-txt">
    Temp2
  </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function chumpage() {
  var chump = document.getElementsByClassName('first-txt');
  for (var i = 0; i < chump.length; i++) {
    chump[i].innerText = "temp3";
  }
}
```